# Using Thrust counting iterators with strides

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am looking for a way to use the `thrust::counting_iterator` function in order to parallelize the following for loop:

```
for (int stride = 0 ; stride < N * M ; stride+=M) // N iterations
{
    // Body of the loop
}
```

*Here is how the code looks like:*

```
struct functor ()
{
   __host__ __device__ void operator() (const int i)
   {
      // Body of the loop
   }
}

thrust::counting_iterator<int> it1(0);
thrust::counting_iterator<int> it2 = it1 + N * M;
thrust::for_each (it1 , it2 , functor());
```

I'm aware that `counting_iterator` increments iterators by 1, so is there a way to increment by M?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just multiply the `i` variable by `M` in your functor?

If `M` is known at compile time, it could be:

```
struct functor 
{
   __host__ __device__ void operator() (const int my_i)
   {
      int i = my_i *M;
      // Body of the loop
   }
};

thrust::counting_iterator<int> it1(0);
thrust::counting_iterator<int> it2 = it1 + N;
thrust::for_each (it1 , it2 , functor());
```

If `M` is known only at runtime, we can pass it as an initializing parameter to the functor:

```
struct functor 
{
   int my_M;
   functor(int _M) : my_M(_M) ();
   __host__ __device__ void operator() (const int my_i)
   {
      int i = my_i *my_M;
      // Body of the loop
   }
};

thrust::counting_iterator<int> it1(0);
thrust::counting_iterator<int> it2 = it1 + N;
thrust::for_each (it1 , it2 , functor(M));
```

You could also wrap a counting iterator in a transform iterator, which takes the counting iterator and multiplies it by M:

```
struct functor 
{
   __host__ __device__ void operator() (const int i)
   {
      // Body of the loop
   }
};

using namespace thrust::placeholders;
thrust::counting_iterator<int> it1(0);
thrust::counting_iterator<int> it2 = it1 + N;
thrust::for_each (make_transform_iterator(it1, _1 * M) , thrust::make_transform_iterator(it2, _1 * M) , functor());
```

This last example uses [thrust placeholder expressions](http://thrust.github.io/doc/namespaceplaceholders.html), although it could be realized equivalently with an additional trivial functor which returns its argument multiplied by its parameter.

Here is a fully worked example showing all 3 methods:

```
$ cat t492.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#define N 5
#define M 4
using namespace thrust::placeholders;

struct my_functor_1
{
  __host__ __device__  void operator() (const int i)
  {
    printf("functor 1 value: %d\n", i);
  }
};

struct my_functor_2
{
   __host__ __device__ void operator() (const int my_i)
   {
    int i = my_i*M;
    printf("functor 2 value: %d\n", i);
   }
};

struct my_functor_3
{
   int my_M;
   my_functor_3(int _M) : my_M(_M) {};
   __host__ __device__ void operator() (const int my_i)
   {
      int i = my_i *my_M;
      printf("functor 3 value: %d\n", i);
   }
};


int main(){
  thrust::counting_iterator<int> it1(0);
  thrust::counting_iterator<int> it2 = it1 + N;
  thrust::for_each(thrust::host, it1, it2, my_functor_1());
  thrust::for_each(thrust::host, it1, it2, my_functor_2());
  thrust::for_each(thrust::host, it1, it2, my_functor_3(M));
  thrust::for_each(thrust::host, thrust::make_transform_iterator(it1, _1 * M), thrust::make_transform_iterator(it2, _1 * M), my_functor_1());
  return 0;
}


$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t492 t492.cu
$ ./t492
functor 1 value: 0
functor 1 value: 1
functor 1 value: 2
functor 1 value: 3
functor 1 value: 4
functor 2 value: 0
functor 2 value: 4
functor 2 value: 8
functor 2 value: 12
functor 2 value: 16
functor 3 value: 0
functor 3 value: 4
functor 3 value: 8
functor 3 value: 12
functor 3 value: 16
functor 1 value: 0
functor 1 value: 4
functor 1 value: 8
functor 1 value: 12
functor 1 value: 16
$
```

Comment: The 3rd method (with make_transform_iterator) is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of the [arbitrary transformation example](https://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/arbitrary_transformation.cu) and of the [strided range example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/strided_range.cu).

Below, I'm considering an example in which the transformation is

```
D[i] = A[i] + B[i] * C[i]
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

#include <thrust/fill.h>

// for printing
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <ostream>

#define STRIDE 2

template <typename Iterator>
class strided_range
{
    public:

    typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type difference_type;

    struct stride_functor : public thrust::unary_function<difference_type,difference_type>
    {
        difference_type stride;

        stride_functor(difference_type stride)
            : stride(stride) {}

        __host__ __device__
        difference_type operator()(const difference_type& i) const
        {
            return stride * i;
        }
    };

    typedef typename thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>                   CountingIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::transform_iterator<stride_functor, CountingIterator> TransformIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::permutation_iterator<Iterator,TransformIterator>     PermutationIterator;

    // type of the strided_range iterator
    typedef PermutationIterator iterator;

    // construct strided_range for the range [first,last)
    strided_range(Iterator first, Iterator last, difference_type stride)
        : first(first), last(last), stride(stride) {}

    iterator begin(void) const
    {
        return PermutationIterator(first, TransformIterator(CountingIterator(0), stride_functor(stride)));
    }

    iterator end(void) const
    {
        return begin() + ((last - first) + (stride - 1)) / stride;
    }

    protected:
    Iterator first;
    Iterator last;
    difference_type stride;
};

struct arbitrary_functor
{
    template <typename Tuple>
    __host__ __device__
    void operator()(Tuple t)
    {
        // D[i] = A[i] + B[i] * C[i];
        thrust::get<3>(t) = thrust::get<0>(t) + thrust::get<1>(t) * thrust::get<2>(t);
    }
};


int main(void)
{
    // allocate storage
    thrust::device_vector<float> A(5);
    thrust::device_vector<float> B(5);
    thrust::device_vector<float> C(5);
    thrust::device_vector<float> D(5);

    // initialize input vectors
    A[0] = 3;  B[0] = 6;  C[0] = 2; 
    A[1] = 4;  B[1] = 7;  C[1] = 5; 
    A[2] = 0;  B[2] = 2;  C[2] = 7; 
    A[3] = 8;  B[3] = 1;  C[3] = 4; 
    A[4] = 2;  B[4] = 8;  C[4] = 3; 

    typedef thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator Iterator;
    strided_range<Iterator> posA(A.begin(), A.end(), STRIDE);
    strided_range<Iterator> posB(B.begin(), B.end(), STRIDE);
    strided_range<Iterator> posC(C.begin(), C.end(), STRIDE);
    strided_range<Iterator> posD(D.begin(), D.end(), STRIDE);

    // apply the transformation
    thrust::for_each(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(posA.begin(), posB.begin(), posC.begin(), posD.begin())),
                 thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(posA.end(), posB.end(), posC.end(), posD.end())),
                 arbitrary_functor());

    // print the output
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    std::cout << A[i] << " + " << B[i] << " * " << C[i] << " = " << D[i] << std::endl;
}
```