# How to use thrust::remove_if to check and remove blocks 2×i and 2×i+1 together

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am using Cuda C++, and I have a big array *Arr* including 64-bit unsigned integers in a form like the below:

```
Arr = {a1, b1, a2, b2, ..., an, bn}
```

The number of items in *Arr* is *2n* which is an even number. Now, given a boolean function f(int a, int b), I wonder if I can use thrust::remove_if to check f(a1,b1), f(a2, b2), ..., f(an, bn) and remove both consecutive numbers (ai, bi) together if needed?

Comment: You could use a zip iterator to take two slices of the array with alternating pieces, to pass to the thrust algorithm.  You can then operate on pairs.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks Robert. I was thinking about zip iterator, however, I did not know how to zip all two conswcutive blocks together? I mean indices (0,1) together, (1,2) together until (2n-1, 2n) and pass them through Thrust functions. I really appreciate it and will choose the best answer if you could make a simple example for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `zip_iterator`, I think a simpler approach is just to reinterpret the array of 64-bit integers as an array of `thrust::pair`.  here is an example:

```
$ cat t2157.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

struct my_remove
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(T t){
    return (thrust::get<0>(t) > thrust::get<1>(t));
  }
};

const size_t n = 32768;
const size_t s = 2*n;
using mt=unsigned long long;
using dt=thrust::pair<mt,mt>;

int main(){

  thrust::device_vector<mt> A(s);
  thrust::sequence(A.begin(), A.end());
  A[0] = 2;  // expecting removal of the first pair
  thrust::copy_n(A.begin(), 6, std::ostream_iterator<mt>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  auto D = thrust::device_pointer_cast<dt>(reinterpret_cast<dt *>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(A.data())));
  thrust::remove_if(D, D+n, my_remove());
  thrust::copy_n(A.begin(), 6, std::ostream_iterator<mt>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t2157 t2157.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2157
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
2,1,2,3,4,5,
2,3,4,5,6,7,
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert. It is really helpful. Just quick question. Can we use more inputs in functions like my_remove() that we pass to Thrust functions? I think no. But, I am asking because I need some other stuff for deciding on keeping or removing a pair, but I don't want to use global variables.

Comment: If its a global variable, you can pass it to the functor at the point of the algorithm call. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853568/using-thrust-counting-iterators-with-strides/24854975#24854975) is an example, specifically the 2nd code snippet "if `M` is known only at runtime".